# why do I need the display:block

Tags: html, list, block

If I run the markup as it is now the `<li>` element is not within the `<ul>` element.
But if I add this style `display:block;` to `#nav a` so the complete `#nav a` declaration looks like this then the `<li>` element is within `<ul>`.

```
#nav a {
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:8px 16px;
  color:#333;
  text-decoration:none;
  border:1px solid #9B8748;
  border-bottom:none;
  background:#F9E9A9;
 }
```

Can anybody explain why the `<li>` element is within the `<ul>` when I add `display:block` to `#nav a`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   body {
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:small;
      width:720px;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
   }
   #nav {
       float:left;
       width:100%;
       margin:0;
       padding:10px 0 0 46px;
       list-style:none;
       background:#FFCB2D;
   }
   #nav li {
      float:left;
      margin:0 1px 0 0;
      padding:0;
      font-family:"Lucida Grande", "sans-serif";
      font-size:90%;
   }
   #nav a {
      /* display:block;*/
       margin:0;
       padding:8px 16px;
       color:#333;
       text-decoration:none;
       border:1px solid #9B8748;
       border-bottom:none;
       background:#F9E9A9;
   }
   #nav a:hover {
       color:#333;
       padding-bottom:5px;
       border-color:#727377;
       background:#fff;
   }
</style>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Chapter 3</title>
</head>
<body>
 <ul id="nav">
  <li id="t-intro"><a href="/">Introduction</a></li>
  <li id="t-about"><a href="about.html">About Lance</a></li>
  <li id="t-news"><a href="news.html">News &amp; Events</a></li>
  <li id="t-sponsors"><a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
 </ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update your code...

see following http://jsfiddle.net/LUzbR/

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="t-intro"><a href="/">Introduction</a></li>
  <li id="t-about"><a href="about.html">About Lance</a></li>
  <li id="t-news"><a href="news.html">News &amp; Events</a></li>
  <li id="t-sponsors"><a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
 body
   {
      font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:small;
      width:720px;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
   }

   #nav
   {
       float:left;
       width:100%;
       margin: 0px;
       padding:10px 0px 0px 46px;
       display: block;
       list-style:none;
       background:#FFCB2D;
   }

   #nav li
   {
      float:left;
      display: block;
      margin:0 1px 0 0;
      padding:0;
      font-family:"Lucida Grande", "sans-serif";
      font-size:90%;
   }

   #nav a
   {
      /* display:block;*/
       margin:0px;
       padding:8px 16px;
       color:#333;
       text-decoration:none;
       border:1px solid #9B8748;
       border-bottom:none;
       background:#F9E9A9;
       display: block;
   }


   #nav a:hover
   {
       color:#333;
       padding-bottom:5px;
       border-color:#727377;
       background:#fff;
   }
```

Comment: Would you consider explaining this code a bit, and maybe narrow things down to the part that's actually addressing the specific question here?

Answer (score 0):

You're floating the #nav element on the left, so all `<li>` elements will appear outside of that container. Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to your #nav for starters, although there's probably more that could be done to clean up your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Without adding `display: block`, `a` elements are treated as `display: inline`. As such, when calculating the size of their parents (`height` is default to `auto`), the `padding` of the `a` element is omitted, while it is included in cases of `display: block`.